# Как делают обработку коллизии для множества одинаковых объектов?

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня падают вниз экрана объекты и останавливаются там. Как только их становится четыре, они должны пойти в одну сторону, а потом взаимодействовать друг с другом - ближайший к краю останавливается, второй упирается в первого, третий залезает на первых двух, а последний на третьего. И я все никак не могу придумать, как сделать так, чтобы они не путались - при столкновениях разных объектов такой проблемы нет. Есть задумка сделать что-то типа такого - поделить экран на условные клетки, и при одновременном соблюдении условий (все упираются друг в друга) сделать цикл с шагом i =+10, например. Каждому объекту присвоить булевое значение а1 - а4, б1- б4, и, при нахождении в этой точке запускать какое-то действие (идти вперёд или идти вверх, к примеру). Но эта идея мне не очень нравится, есть способы лучше?

Comment: Есть: присваивайте каждому экземпляру уникальный идентификатор в момент его создания

Comment: Тоже была такая идея, но как его потом найти? Допустим, эти объекты создаются по порядку (а там будет пул, что немного осложняет - в libgdx я бы в основном классе сделал счётчик, увеличивающийся при каждом создании, а в классе объекта переменную, которой присваивается значение этого счётчика, а в юнити как-то не знаю), но вот располагаются они абсолютно случайным образом - первый может быть по счёту третьим, и второй не долетит до низа экрана и создастся вообще пятый объект, который на экране будет четвертым.

Comment: Хотя нет, найти не проблема - вешаю на камеру скрипт с идентификатором и координатами. А вот то, что они на экране могут быть вразнобой все ещё проблема

Comment: @KremSoda `то, что они на экране могут быть вразнобой все ещё проблема` - отсортировать в массиве их по удаленности к краю экрана - будет понятно кто где.......`Vector3.Distance` к примеру или чем-то подобным

Comment: @KremSoda Как мне казалось, ваша проблема только в том, чтобы отличить один экземпляр от другого - идентификаторы для этого и нужны. Ну а дальше пусть объект сам добавляется в список при достаточном приближении к краю экрана, как написал Алексей. Список заполняется - запускается действие, описанное вами. Строго говоря, вам даже не нужно самостоятельно вводить идентификаторы, достаточно просто помещать объект в список